# Decoding images from NOAA satellite APT signals

Tags: demodulation, hilbert-transform

I've been working on a decoder for these APT images for a while now. I started years ago, in Python, and was able to implement a working decoder quickly. A few months ago, I came back to the project and decided to move to C++. I have not been making good progress, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_picture_transmission) for a description of the signal. Briefly, 256-level 4160 Bd image data is amplitude modulated onto a 2400-Hz subcarrier, which is frequency modulated onto a 137-MHz RF carrier.

Question the first: how is it possible (or rather, how it is meaningful) to use a carrier with frequency lower than the message? Is my misunderstanding perhaps to do with the frequency content of the message itself, rather than the rate it has been sampled at? Or something else?

I have the signal stored as a WAV file, 16-bit LPCM at 20800 Hz. I read these samples into an array, working one line of decoded image at a time. APT is two lines per second, so my array contains 10400 elements.

Now, the problem seems to come down to AM demodulation. It is my understanding that the proper way to do this is via computing the magnitude of the analytic signal. I do so by taking the DFT of my array, setting the negative frequency components to zero, and doubling the positive elements. Then iDFT back, and take the magnitudes as the demodulated signal.

I do some median filtering, do a naïve low-pass by zeroing bins in DFT, scale to 256 levels, and generate an image. Seems relatively simple -- so why does the output look so horrible? I am not sure what else to try. From my explanation, is there something I am doing I ought not be, etc.?

[image: My decoded image]

The bars on the right side look to me to be the telemetry frames, so it seems that my process is "working" in some sense. I'm not sure what the source of the high-frequency "circle" curves are you can see in the image.

Comment: It's often a good instinct to mistrust Wikipedia's wording on signal descriptions! On a quick skim, I couldn't find an authorative source for the APT standard. Do you happen to know one?

Comment: Are you translating your working Python code to C++? If so, the problem is likely in your implementation of the envelope detector or a filter. Maybe use an existing library, like liquidsdr, first, and then replace each function with your own code, one by one?

Comment: @MarcusMüller https://noaasis.noaa.gov/NOAASIS/pubs/Users_Guide-Building_Receive_Stations_March_2009.pdf

Comment: @MBaz found that, too, but it seems too vague to actually be guidance...

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, somewhat surprisingly, I also was unable to find such a source. There is the user guide MBaz provided, and there is an archived page in Wikipedia’s references section which seems to be the source of the diagrams (and lots of the wording) in the article

Comment: :/ then, I'd look into other decoders. By the way, why not LRPT?

Comment: @MBaz Yes, I agree, this does seem likely. But, it’s also where my mind has been for the last long while I’ve been working on this, and I can’t find any errors. Filtering etc aside, sampling the Hilbert transform ought to get me a better image than the above. But the Hilbert transform I’m using is basically just FFTW’s example implementation, which seems unlikely to be flawed. Many people claim to have success by resampling the WAV to 4 * 2400 Hz, and then using the 90-deg phase between samples to extract the amplitude. No luck for me with that either, and that’s an even easier implementation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I’ve found several, and they all seem to use the “resample to four times the carrier frequency, and use the 90-deg phase difference between samples here to compute the amplitude”-method, which I’m also unable to get to work, despite its overwhelming simplicity. At least with what I’ve done above, there is some evidence of underlying structure. No such luck with this resampling technique

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, I’d like to move there too eventually! But I figured APT would be a simpler start.

Comment: @RileyScottJacob not so sure about an analog picture transmission being easier to deal with than a digital mode!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Evidently! The thing that drew me to start this project the first time (over two years ago!) was the lack of a feature rich, free software decoder for APT. I had left the project for a long time, and noticed someone had forked it a few months ago, which to me showed there was still interest in the (dying) protocol. So I decided I’d move to Qt/C++, my framework of choice, and try to implement a strong toolkit for working with APT. It has been a long time since one has been around.

Comment: And I promise that will probably be very appreciated!

Comment: This is a very old signal, so it likely could be processed without FFTs.  The PDF document mentioned by @MBaz above says that the 2400Hz carrier is tracked by a PLL.  So you need a PLL with a bandwidth small enough to not suffer from the AM modulation, but wide enough to account for the doppler drift that you would see.  Where did you get the wave file?  Do you know that it is good?